# Android and Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, build, apk

I have tried my hands on compiling a Java project with Ant from scratch. Is it possible in Android too? If I have only the source code, can I compile the project? If so, how?

Comment: The source code is not sufficient, you'll need to have a working installation of Android SDK

Comment: Yes, that is installed. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

Read the [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to keep in mind:

1. Android supports ant build scripts, the developer website, and the tools provided, show you how to do this easily.
2. But if you want to support different versions of android with a single set of scripts the best way is to write custom ant scripts (a single set, that will compile for all versions) for this as SDK Tools v5, v6, v7 and v8 all do ant builds differently. This requires some effort and planning.

Comment: Its a bad idea to create different builds targetting different versions. Read this post - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html - to learn how to make your application take advantage of new features and yet be able to work on older Android OS versions.

Comment: Ah, I see where my answer can be misunderstood as suggesting different scripts, I will edit it.